# It is possible to clear all error boundaries in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have an application with multiple components each wrapped in an error boundary. Sometimes, their children components throw errors which bubble up to the error boundary.

Here's a contrived example: https://codesandbox.io/s/throwing-many-errors-yirbgc

[image]

Each "Failed to load" is displaying an error boundary. I want to be able to click "refresh"  to reset all of them.

Is it possible?

Comment: Anything wrong with the error recovery methods given in the package documentation?

Comment: @super Which package documentation? Error boundaries are a built-in React concept. If you're talking about `react-query` or `react-error-boundary`, neither of them are necessary for the example, it was just to make things look cleaner.

Comment: Both reacts own documentation as well as react-error-boundary's documentation gives examples.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is very crude and far from perfect but you could try something in the lines of remembering the resets of the errors given by [the error boundary props](https://resetErrorBoundary)

`const errorResets = useRef<Function[]>([]);`

```js
<button
        onClick={() => {
          // I want to reset all my error boundaries
          alert(`resetting ${errorResets.current.length} errors`);
          errorResets.current.forEach((reset) => {
            console.log(reset);
            reset();
          });
          errorResets.current = [];
        }}
      >
        Refresh
</button>
```

```js
<ErrorBoundary
        FallbackComponent={({ error, resetErrorBoundary }) => {
          errorResets.current = [...errorResets.current, resetErrorBoundary];
          return <h3>Failed to load</h3>;
        }}
      >
        <MyRow />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Comment: I know that I could gather resets into a ref or a context higher up in the tree, but I was hoping it would be possible to make the call "top down" instead of "down-up" if you will.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not exist to my knowlegde